# Large number of plots from external csv file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

I'm looking to draw a large number of lines/datasets (around 150~200, 50 points each) on a single window using pgfplot. The data is imported from a csv file created with matlab. I've seen several memory issues with problems similar to this, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Maybe you can try already and see where and when problems occur?